# Add items to shopping cart AJAX Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, shopping-cart

I'm using **Laravel** for ecommerce website and adding items by this way:

```
<div class="product-icon-container">
    <a href="{{ route('product.addToCart', ['id' => $product->id]) }}"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
</div>
```

Can you suggest AJAX solution to adding items to cart without refreshing page?

Answer (score 3):

You can  capture onclick and submit asynchronously with [Jquery](http://jquery.com).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.product-icon-container').find('a').click(function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('href')
                ,success: function(response) {
                    alert(response)
                }
            });
            return false; //for good measure
        });
</script>
```